# center div content vertically and horizontally not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have a website with more than one section but my website don't have scroll, so when i want to go to each section i should click on that section's button from menu... whatever, the website should display each section content as a cover page (one page) with full width and height, with centering the content of the main div of that section.

i tried to do that with `vertical-align:middle`, with `display table-cell` .. i wrote the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zazsvazp/)

welcome div should display in the center of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `html{height:100%;}` and `.container-fluid{height:100%;}`

Comment: there's an error in your answer (semi-colon in wrong place).
I can't edit this answer because "Edits must be at least 6 characters"... maybe you can correct

Comment: Yea you're right, the keyboard hates me today, it should be fixed now

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the following:

```
html,
.container-fluid {
    height:100%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zazsvazp/4/)

Answer (score 0):

add margin: 50% auto; in welcome class

```
  .welcome {
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
    color:#000;
    margin:50% auto;
  }
```